# Why are there double references on the header of 2nd page?

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[singlespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[headheight=1in,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{
   THIS IS HEADER
 }

\chead{%
TITLE
}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{Insert Title Here}

\author[]{} % Please leave Author-field blank for blind review and remove information that may identify the author(s)
 
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\vspace{-6em}
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textit{Keywords: Please provide 5 keywords that describe your work}}
\newline
\end{center}

\section*{Abstract}

MainBody \ref{A}.

\printbibliography



\end{document}
```

below is `sample.bib`:

```
@misc{A, title={some title}, volume={25}, number={11}, journal={First Monday}, author={A,B,C}, year={2020}, month={Oct.} }
```

Comment: You have not provided any code to allow anyone to debug the issue. If it happens for every section then you have presumably specified the left third and the right third of the heading to both show the section. If the left is showing sections and the right is showing subsections then you presumably have the references mis-configured to be a subsection inside a section both called references

Comment: if log in from pc i can see the code.

Comment: You have posted some code fragment but do as you are asking us to do copy that to a new directory and run it to debug the heading in the reference section. You will find it is an incomplete fragment and makes no pdf at all.

Comment: sorry, changed.

Comment: Please make sure (1) your example actually compiles, I get an error on `\printbibliography[t]` and (2) that it shows your problem. Additionally, please remove everything unrelated.

Comment: `! Package keyval Error: t undefined.` And if I try to scroll past that error I get a 1 page pdf file that does not have the heading shown in your question.  Please make sure that the output image you show is generated by the code that you post otherwise no one can help.

Comment: Please always test the exact MWE you want to post in a new, empty folder (or a new, empty project if you are using Overleaf) before you submit it. Make sure that the MWE does not produce unrelated errors or warnings and that it actually reproduces the issue you are asking about. As others have mentioned the code as posted will produce an error about the unknown option `t` to `\printbibliography`. It will also not produce a bibliography for us, since we don't have your file `sample.bib` and since there are no citations in the document.

Comment: sorry, changed again.

Comment: I'm sorry to be a pain, but did you actually test the example code you posted in a new, empty folder? It seems that you confused `\ref` and `\cite` in your code. You want to cite `A`, not reference it. If I run your code exactly as it is in the question it does not produce a bibliography and no "References" header. If I change `\ref` to `\cite` the document compiles and has a bibliography, but I am not sure if it shows the effect you are asking about. It really is important that you run the MWE and check that it reproduces your issue.

Comment: I guessed what the MWE was supposed to show and went ahead and posted an answer, but I am not completely sure that I got what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's standard behaviour of `biblatex` (and standard LaTeX `thebibliography`) to issue column titles for the bibliography and those are picked up by `fancyhdr`.

The effect can be reproduced with `biblatex` in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{TITLE}

% just for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

MainBody \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and with standard `thebibliography`/BibTeX in

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chead{TITLE}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}

\section{Lorem}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

MainBody \cite{inbook-full}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

[image: Double "REFERENCES" header]

In these examples, note how other `\section` commands also produce column headers.

The solution depends on what you want. If you want to get rid of all sectioning column headers, replace

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\chead{
   THIS IS HEADER
 }

\chead{%
TITLE
}
```

with

```
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[c]{TITLE}
```

i.e.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[c]{TITLE}

% just for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

MainBody \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Just "TITLE"]

If you want to keep the sectioning column headers, you could try something like

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[c]{TITLE}

\makeatletter
\defbibheading{bibliography}[\refname]{%
  \section*{#1}%
  \@mkboth{\abx@MakeMarkcase{#1}}{}}
\makeatother

% just for testing
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\section{Lorem}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

MainBody \cite{sigfridsson}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: the replacement of `\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[c]{TITLE}` works. Thx!